# Links not working properly from a link post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, hyperlink, grid, shortcode

I created some posts in the link format where i inserted my link I want this post to take me to, but when I click it it just keeps taking me to the permalink of that post. I am using the post in a "grid post" shortcode that looks like this, and I was hoping that by clicking on the link button it would take me to the link I inserted.  But it's not.  Here is the shortcode:

```
[posts_grid columns="3" rows="2" order_by="date" order="DESC" thumb_width="175" thumb_height="150" meta="no" excerpt_count="10" link="yes" link_text="show me more" category="CAROUSEL"]
```

Not sure what I am missing here.  thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to share the code written by you for this shortcode.I think problem is with its implementation

Comment: Hi, I took the code from the wordpress admin. where do you need me to share this.